# Start and stop div scrolling between two other divs

Tags: jquery

Someone else recently helped me out with the start of this question but I'm after a little more help. I currently have this working -

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw),
    $bumper = $(elem),
    bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
    thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
    setPosition = function(){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#one').followTo('#two');
```

Example here - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/)

This stops a div from scrolling once it reaches the border of another div - works great. What I'm stuck trying to figure out now is how I can make the scrolling div START at a div, then scroll down and stop at another div as it does in this example. Anyone got any ideas?

Here's a terrible illustration of it - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1450/). The blue section SHOULD sit underneath the yellow section until you reach it. I just can't figure out how that's possible due to my limited brain function.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another parameter to your function to pass the start element, then set some vars inside your function to store its `offset().top + height()` as the start position, then just add another `if` to check if the `scrollTop()` value is lower than the start one, like this:

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function (from, bumper) { //renamed "elem" to "bumper", to 
    var $this = this,                     //prevent ambiguity
        $window = $(windw),
        $from = $(from),
        $bumper = $(bumper),
        $startPos = $from.offset().top + $from.height(), //new start position
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() < $startPos) { //new if < startPos
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: $startPos //resets element to start position
                });
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#one').followTo('#half', '#two');
```

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Tgm6Y/1455/)

Comment: Ah, this is absolutely perfect. Thanks a lot, I've been stuck on this a while. Legend.

Comment: I know this in an old topic, Fabricio, but I am using your code and am having a problem. Can you (or anyone else) help? Please see here: https://jsfiddle.net/fLyrg57t/20/

Comment: @Eddy I'm not quite sure what problem you are experiencing, please post a new question if you are still experiencing issues so that I or someone else may be able to help. :)

Comment: @Fabrício I have started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492032/divs-fixed-and-unfixed-toggle-between-two-absolute-divs