# Please show me how to run a Javascript function in my browser

Tags: javascript

I have no experience with javascript, but I found some code from this thread:

[Start and stop div scrolling between two other divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993705/start-and-stop-div-scrolling-between-two-other-divs)

and I want to use it in my website. The problem is, I can't get it to work in my browser. So far I have all the code from the jsfiddle examples (the first one) in the link in separate html, css, and javascript documents and everything is linked fine. But it doesn't work like it does in the example. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to get this functioning?

Thank you.

Comment: What web browser are you using? Do you get a javascript error when you try to run it? Can you describe what it does do? You mentioned it doesn't work like in the example.

Comment: This is not a question; it's a request for a tutorial and doesn't belong here.

Comment: I am using chrome. And I apologize for not asking in the form of a question, I was just looking for some help. It basically just runs the blue box as it were fixed and the other two boxes scroll over the top of it in normal html flow.

Comment: Taking code from someone else then saying "Oh I'll ask a question to get what I want" You should definitely read up on javascript. W3Schools is a great place to start.

Comment: I am just using it to learn and as a starting point. There is nothing wrong with that. I have been to W3Schools. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply copied it all, you either did not link in [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) or are (most likely) trying to execute the JavaScript before the DOM is ready.

---

Edit:

Linking in jQuery. The [fiddle you refer to](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/) uses jQuery 1.6, so one way is to load from *code.jquery.com* or *ajax.googleapis.com*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
or
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Executing code at the right time

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    // your code here

}, false);
```

Comment: Hey Shhac, thanks for a quick response. What exactly do I need to do to link in jquery? So far, I am testing all the code as is in the example. I tried linking to an external javascript sheet using the <script src=""> tag.

Comment: @user1721301, I have updated my answer with this information. If you want to see exactly how the fiddle looks when it is combined, please view the source of the bottom right frame: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Tgm6Y/1447/show/

Comment: Shacc, I can't thank you enough. I didn't really understand linking in jQuery until you posted the code. But I have it working and I am going to see if it applies to what I am designing. Again, I sincerely appreciate it! Have a good one.